# How to validate card before billing

Tags: php, validation, stripe-payments, billing

I am using [stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) in PHP. I have a customer and a card added to the customer in stripe. The added card is the default card for the customer. Is there a way to validate the card with the `card id` of the default card of the customer before billing the card?

Comment: Query into your database, retrieve the card number (or it's hashed version) and compare it with the card number that the user inserted. Then handle this appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a customer in Stripe from a card token we automatically run a $0/$1 authorization on the card to make sure it's valid. This means that is the customer create succeeds then the card is valid.

That doesn't guarantee that you will be able to charge the card though as the banks ultimately decide whether or not they want to let a charge go through and this can depend on a lot of factors. The only way to make sure that a charge can go through is to create the charge itself and see whether it succeeds or not.